# Directive hierarchy & bindToController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angular-directive

I encountered an issue while writing an AngularJS directive.
I'm actually trying to melt two principles, directive inheritance and using the controller object (the famous `this`) instead of `$scope`.

I have something like that :

```js
angular
.module('app')
.directive('dLed', dLed);

function dLed() {
    return {
        require: ['^dFeature', 'dLed'],
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : true,
        controllerAs : 'vm',
        link : linker,
        controller: ledController,
        bindToController : true,
        templateUrl : 'app/features/templates/led.html'
    };
```

In the linker, I want to inject to my local controller the `feature` object that is inherited from my parent directive's controller:

```js
    function linker(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        var featureCtrl = ctrls[0];
        var localCtrl = ctrls[1];

        localCtrl.feature = featureCtrl.feature;
    }
```

And then, I want to add some extra behaviour in my controller, based on the same `feature` object:

```js
    function ledController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.getClasses = getClasses;

        function getClasses() {
            var classes = "";

            classes += vm.feature.state?"on":"off";

            if (vm.feature.options.color) {
                classes += " " + vm.feature.options.color;
            }   
            return classes;
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that the `localCtrl` object passed as parameter in my linker function is a *clone* of the real controller object, so when the `feature` is added, it is not accessible from `ledController` function.

However, the `feature` object is well found during the compilation of the template.

Here is a plunker of the application : http://plnkr.co/edit/Wn3JbSSVEG0aBOEckmzL?p=

What is the problem ? Am I using the controller (or the linker) the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want directive to share data between its `controller` and `link` function, one way to achieve this is to put that data on `$scope`.

And in this case, it looks as though you'd like to use the parent controller (`localCtrl`) in the controller of your sub-directive. And since the parent controller is only injected into the linking function, we need to attach this variable to `$scope` is we want it available in the `controller`:

I updated the plunker to achieve this, and if you pop open the console, you'll note the object is now available.

**Link**

```
scope.vm = localCtrl;
```

**Controller**

```
var localCtrl = $scope.vm;
```

**Forked plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/CEUfogdoI79iaSTr1x4n

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but here you just bind the scope to the controller via the ```vm``` object.  
Why the controller passed to the linker is not the "real" controller object but a clone of it ? Where am I supposed to write my specific code ? Should I do like [this](plnkr.co/edit/i3PpovuvxHsO1LI6nHbW?p=preview) ?     
I want to get rid of the ```$scope``` object in my controller...